# jquery valid() not function

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, model-view-controller

I am not able to find where is the issue occure
I am using mvc and I want to check validation using jquery client side

Bundle

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery_1.11.1.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

jquery

```
$('form').submit(function () {
    if ($(this).valid()) {
       alert("valid success");
    }         
});
```

I am stuck in issue that,

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).valid is not a function

Where I am going to wrong

Thank you.

Comment: is the jquery validate library included before you are trying to use it ? Check the view source and see the order.

Comment: yes, Its loaded

Comment: Refresh your browser cache / reload the page / make sure script load / name correct

Comment: `$('form').validate()` should be used before `valid()` - refer to [documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/).

Comment: Check for any other inclusions of jQuery. For example, if you include another copy of jQuery after the validate plugins, they will be removed. The easiest way to do so is view the rendered page source and search for _".js"_

Comment: @Phil how can I do this ?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, No! The `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` plugin configures the `$.validator`.

Comment: It is already there